# Using "socialize" as a word to mean "make something known"

Tags: single-word-requests, writing

Is "socialize" the right word to mean "make something common knowledge" in this context?

The context is for a resume -- the particular accomplishment is some key idea/method/process that I started using, and which caught on via subtle/indirect means, such as using it and sharing, rather than more direct means, such as policy or training.

I'm trying to use it in a bullet point like so:

> Discovered and socialized a method for determining latency from obscure data fields, enabling us to detect a major yet subtle issue impacting performance...

I'm pretty sure socialize is the right word, but I'm wondering if there's a better word. I've heard the word I'm thinking of has also been used in an individual/self context, like "Let me go and ____ myself to this X topic", although this might have been in a business setting where big words are abused...

Comment: Socialize looks like an excellent choice for your technical audience. It is jargon, but standard for the IT reader.

Comment: I think the word you want is ***popularize***, not ***socialize*** (feasibly ***disseminate*** or ***publicize***).

Answer (score 2):

I find *socialize* to be completely the wrong word (and I worked in IT for decades). From context, I can just about work out what you're meaning to say by it, but if I encountered it in a CV, I would go "This person is trying to use long words that they don't understand".

On the other hand, I can't think of a good word for it: *introduce* and *promulgate* have something of the nature, but they're not right. I think I'd recast it:

> Discovered a method ... which has spread widely among ...

(I think it's a plus to say just who the group are where it has spread).

Answer (score 1):

OED has three current senses for *socialize:*

> 2. *transitive.* To civilize, to make suitable for society. Now chiefly *Social Sciences:* to instil in (a person) the values and norms of his or her society or group.
> 3. *intransitive.* To be sociable, participate in social activities; to mix socially with.
> 4. *transitive.* To make socialist in nature; to establish or develop according to the principles of socialism; *spec.* to bring under state ownership or public control, to finance with public funds. Also *intransitive.*

None has the meaning you intend, although I have seen the word mean "to make known in society." Even if it's jargon in your field, it might be advisable not to use *socialize.* It's not a meaning which OED has seen often enough even to mention.

There is also the point that even with the meaning "to make known in society," **you haven't socialized the method.** It's become known through osmosis and the recommendation of others. [Colin Fine's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/604989/18696) addresses this point.

Answer (score 0):

The common word is "familiarize".

Socialise, in BE, has the meaning of "to cause to behave in a manner acceptable to society."

OED **familiarize**

> **2.a.** transitive (reflexive). **To make oneself knowledgeable about something, esp. through direct experience; to acquaint oneself with something; (also) to habituate or accustom oneself.**
>
> 2009   P. Carr-Gomm & R. Heygate Bk. Eng. Magic iv. 157   *First familiarise yourself with the Grail stories and their landscape.*
>
> **b.** transitive. **To make (a person, the mind, etc.) well acquainted with or knowledgeable about something; (also) to habituate or accustom. ... Also intransitive.**
>
> 1635   J. Hayward in tr. G. F. Biondi Donzella Desterrada Epist. to Rdr. sig. A3v   *Familiarizing thy memory with Poems of this nature.*
>
> 1906   Jrnl. Inst. Electr. Engineers 37 42   *The gas companies have familiarised the public to the placing of lights within the field of view both for indoor and outdoor lighting.*

Comment: I'd be more convinced by this answer if the second, transitive but not reflexive, usage was accompanied by citations more recent than 1906.  To me *familiarise* is almost always reflexive.